# How to change date format in html

Tags: python, html, calendar

In HTML, I am date type, but it's giving me yyyy-mm-dd. I want to use dd-mm-yyyy format.
Can anyone give me a suggestion?

```
<fieldset style = "font-size:15px;">
        <input type="date" name = "fromdate" placeholder = "FROM: DD-MM-YYYY" />
      </fieldset>
         {% comment %} <option value="2P">2P</option> {% endcomment %}
         <fieldset style = "font-size:15px;">
          <input type="date" name = "todate" placeholder = "FROM: DD-MM-YYYY" />
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> Note: The displayed date format will differ from the actual value —
> the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's
> browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.